# $_FILES empty on image upload

Tags: file

i need help, i'm programing some kind of catalogue and i have a page where clients can upload their logo or images. every page i make is included in index.php and my url looks like something like this www.url.com/index.php?s=upload where "upload" is name of upload.php file.

when i create form on that upload.php file and submit it, $_FILES array is empty.

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"index.php\" />\n";
echo "<input type=\"file\" name=\"image\">\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"s\" value=\"upload\">\n";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Spremi\">\n";
echo "</form>\n";
```

i tried everything and nothing works. $_POST items are returned but $_FILES are empty...

Comment: Does anyone else see the floating `not` tag in text?

Comment: Probably because tagged with "-files"

Comment: Oops, I accidentally broke it :-(

Comment: !!!!!! Pavel :( (15 characters)

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have uploads enabled in your php.ini file:

```
file_uploads = On
```